# How to update and delete data in the JTable and Text File using Update and Delete button?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

```java
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int i = tableRegUser.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableRegUser.getModel();
    if(i>=0){
        model.setValueAt(txtUsername.getText(), i, 3);
        model.setValueAt(txtStaffName.getText(), i, 0);
        model.setValueAt(txtStaffID.getText(), i, 1);
        model.setValueAt(txtPhoneNum.getText(), i, 2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update Successful!");//UPDATE     
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
    }
}

private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    DefaultTableModel tblModel=(DefaultTableModel) tableRegUser.getModel();

    //delete row
    if(tableRegUser.getSelectedRowCount()==1){
        //if single row selected so delete
        tblModel.removeRow(tableRegUser.getSelectedRow());
        txtUsername.setText("");
        txtStaffID.setText("");
        txtStaffName.setText("");
        txtPhoneNum.setText("");
    }
    else{
        if(tableRegUser.getRowCount()==0){
            //if table is empty(no data)than display message
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Table is empty!");
        }else{
            //if table not empty but row is not selected or multiple selected
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select single row to delete!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update and delete in `JTable` and at the same time I want it to be updated in the text file. Please help me.

Please help. My due date is on 18<sup>th</sup> January 2021!!

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear to me what your problem is. Does the code (that you posted in your question) not work? Does pressing the _update_ button **not** update the `JTable`? Does pressing the _delete_ button **not** remove the selected row from the `JTable`? Also, I see nothing in your code that relates to a text file. So is your problem that you don't know how to save the contents of your `JTable` in a text file?

Comment: @Abra my problem is i can't delete the data in the jtable and also text file.

Comment: _i can't delete the data in the jtable_ Do you mean that nothing changes in the `JTable` after you click on the _Delete_ `JButton`? Can you also [edit] your question and post sample data from the text file? Do you load the `DefaultTableModel` with the data in the text file?